# Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10 fail to install mysql-server-8.0

Tags: upgrade, mysql, 19.10

Upgrade from 19.04 finished with errors, then when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`  or  `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.17-0ubuntu2) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
2019-10-23T04:23:50.510438Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2019-10-23T04:23:50.512017Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've temporarily enabled "Pre-released updates (eoan-proposed)" and ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` again with the same results.

I've been searching but I could not find a suitable solution.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I don't mind rolling back to the previous mysql-server version as long as the current database is intact.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Server cannot be started to finish its installation:

```
Error while setting value 'IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'
```

One or multiple of these sql modes are no longer available in the new MySQL version. In your case it is `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`.

See a list of valid modes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode

Edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and remove the non-valid modes from the list at option `sql-mode=...`

Comment: The Default Value didn't work either, but once I change ```sql-mode``` to a blank value it worked.
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Here is how I fixed it.
First backup your files from

```
var/lib/mysql
```

Then purge and reinstall MySQL

```
sudo apt purge mysql* mariadb*
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: I could not install mysql-server - something was broken. I tried something similar to this. It was on a computer that I use to test installation from scratch, so I did not care. I renamed `/var/lib/mysql` to something else, as a backup. I removed mysql-common: `sudo apt remove mysql-common`. This is a dependency for basic stuff. I kept track of every package that was removed together with mysql-common: `colord gnome-control-center hplip libhpmud0 libmysqlclient21 ... a lot more`.

Comment: continuing.... I reinstalled all of them immediately after. I checked the size of the new `/var/lib/mysql` it was larger, which is a good sign. I checked many of the packages that were removed and reinstalled and they seemed fine. I installed mysql-server successfully after that.

Comment: Of course, I would not recommand that with a server in production with active databases. In my case, I had no active databases, except perhaps some databases that come with a fresh installation.